# designing for IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, stylesheet, margin, padding

i have used stylesheet main.css for firefox browser,and ie9.css for IE9 but problem is that style contained in ie9.css is not working on IE9 instead style contained in main.css is working which gives undesirable results?

Comment: Which order did you add the stylesheets in your `<head>`? Without seeing the code it's hard to tell what your problem is...

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand what you're asking. Please elaborate on what you mean by `is working which gives undesirable results`. Also, the rule of thumb about designing for IE only is: don't.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to decypher what you mean without seeing your code.  However to design for IE versions you can use [`conditional comments`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to specify different CSS rules for different versions of Internet Explorer:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
   <link href="ie9.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
```